# log.info using log.isInfoEnabled

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

We are using SLF4J

Based on a recent discussion in the team

```
if(LOG.isDebugEnabled()){
  LOG.debug("hello " + a + " world" + b);
}
```

is better than

```
LOG.debug("hello {} world {}", a, b);
```

because in the latter case, the String `hello {} world {}` is created even if "debug" is not enabled. In other words, we are always creating Strings even when it is not required.

I like the latter version as it improves readability significantly.

Can anybody please provide inputs?

Regards,

Shardul.

**EDIT**

Let me put it differently.

Which is a better approach OR Which is the most widely accepted approach?

Shardul.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, the shorter version does not *create* the "`hello {} world {}`" string. The string is already created and placed in the constant pool during compilation and class loading. You are always referencing the same instance from the constant pool, it is as cheap as referencing constant `int`.

But the string *is* created in the first form since you are using string concatenation.

The only extra overhead is calling `LOG.debug` with three arguments which does nothing as it  calls `isDebugEnabled()` internally. Also chances are it will be inlined.

That being said I would go for shorter form in 99% of the cases. The only situation where I would explicitly call `isDebugEnabled` is when computing the message to be logged has a significant cost:

```
if(LOG.isDebugEnabled()){
  LOG.debug("hello {} world {}", cheap, veryExpensive());
}
```

If `veryExpensive()` is, ekhem, very expensive, then it is smart to avoid calling it if it will be discarded. BTW `veryExpensive()` should not have any [side effects](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2010/05/clean-code-clean-logs-avoid-side.html) and it is hard to imagine long-running, side-effect free method...

Comment: If you have a "veryExpensive()" then create an anoymous object with a toString() calling veryExpensive() and pass that.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Nice trick, however a bit obscure IMHO. In [slf4s](https://github.com/weiglewilczek/slf4s) (Scala wrapper for SLF4J) you can safely call: `LOG.debug("hello " + veryExpensive());` - because the `debug()` argument is a function returning a `String` rather than a `String` itself. That function is only called when logging level is sufficient. So it is pretty similar to your solution - passing a block of code. Pretty neat!

Answer (score 6):

The performance impact of creating the `String` would be negligible. But as [SLF4J documentation](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance) specifies **"...this form does not incur the cost of parameter construction in case the log statement is disabled
"** meaning that the String is not even created.

After some consideration, the "human overhead", i.e. the importance of code clarity made us decide in favor fo the second example. 
More so as there is also overhead involved in calling (and writing and reading) the `isXEnabled` mehod.